# Usage of variable in airflow DAG

Tags: python, airflow

I set the variable with the "`airflow variables`" command in `cli`
I wants to use this variable in `DAG`.
I executed the following command on the terminal
The error continues occurs.

```
 Broken DAG: [/root/airflow/dags/param_test.py] invalid syntax (param_test.py, line 13) 

airflow variables -s sh_path = "/tmp/echo_test.sh"
airflow scheduler
```

here the code :

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

tmpl_search_path = Variable.get ("sh_path")

dag = DAG ('param_test', schedule_interval = '* / 5 * * * *'
           start_date = datetime (2018,9,4), catchup = False)

bash_task = BashOperator (
      task_id = "bash_task"
      bash_command = 'sh '+ {{var.value.tmpl_search_path}},
      dag = dag)

bash_task.set_downstream (python_task)

bash_task1 = BashOperator (
      task_id = 'echo',
      bash_command = 'echo 1',
      dag = dag)

bash_task.set_downstream (bash_task1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to quote the jinja templating. Use it as below:

```
bash_task = BashOperator (
      task_id = "bash_task"
      bash_command = "sh {{var.value.tmpl_search_path}}",
      dag = dag)
```